# IE9: Right-click and 'View source' is opening up in word?

Tags: internet-explorer-9

I have Windows 7 Professional for an OS: I'm not sure what changed, but suddenly in IE9 anytime I view the source of a HTML page it's firing up MS Word and trying to display in Word.

How do I revert my Right-click->'View source' so it no longer opens in word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an option in developer tools that controls what viewer is used to view source.  This may not be your problem but maybe this will help someone else.  Open Developer tools (F12).  Go to File menu and choose `Customize Internet Explorer View Source`.  Then pick which viewer to use.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Didn't realize that was an option. Mine was set to Other. Really odd, since I have changed that. Thanks. That did it!

Answer (score 1):

You have most likely set a file association between HTML files and Word at the operating system level.  The steps to change/remove a file association depend on your version of Windows.

For Windows 8, see [Windows 8 Tip: Change File Associations](http://winsupersite.com/article/windows8/windows-8-tip-change-file-associations-144102)

For Windows 7, see [Change which programs Windows uses by default](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-default-programs#1TC=windows-7) (the video requires Silverlight, but you can view the steps in text and images a little lower on the page).

Change the file association back to Notepad, or your favorite text editor.

Comment: This was the first thing I checked in Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Default Programs\Set Associations, but this was not the cause

Comment: Sorry it doesn't help you.  Perhaps it will help someone else with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is you can find whole step by step demonstration to change default view source.

IE : **Tools->Developer Tools**
Developer Tools : **File Menu->Customize Internet Explorer View Source->Other**

Or you can refer the link : http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/11703/choose-the-text-editor-used-to-view-source-code-in-internet-explorer/

hope it helped